# Can we pass secret name as shared/non-prod/xyz-secret in secretRef in deployment.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to use a common secret between multiple teams and thinking if there's a way to escape the forward slash '/' in the secret-name 'shared/non-prod/xyz-secret' as it is giving me following error:

*a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is 'a-z0-9?(.a-z0-9?)*')*

Regards,
Sanyam

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: names can't contain `/`. Just replace it with something else; maybe `shared-non-prod-xyz-secret`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can name AWS secrets having '/' but not k8s secrets so, use a different name for your ExternalSecrets and use the same name to connect those secrets with Deployment under **secretref**.

It will work as expected.